# Conditional subclassing based on iOS version

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

This may be slightly odd to ask, is there a way to conditionally subclass based on iOS version, essentially:

```
if(iOS version >= 9) {
   @interface CDVWKWebViewEngine : CDVPlugin <CDVWebViewEngineProtocol, WKScriptMessageHandler, WKNavigationDelegate>
} else if(iOS version = 8) {
   @interface CDVWKWebViewEngine : CDVPlugin <WKScriptMessageHandler, WKNavigationDelegate>
}
```

I have the iOS [Cordova WkWebView Engine plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine) and would like to fall back to the UIWebView under iOS 8 (ignore the plugin on iOS 8).

I've found it rather tricky to make the use of this plugin conditional as it is so deeply entrenched into the project once it subclasses the UIWebView default plugin.

Comment: You can do it but you're better off having a single subclass with BOTH implementations and have each function call the correct one you want to use. Maybe instead of inheritance you can use composition.

Answer (score 2):

There are preprocessor macros defined for different versions

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 90000
// code to compile for iOS 9 or greater
#else
// code to compile for les than iOS 9
#endif
```

If you want to take the decision on runtime, you can use [`-systemVersion` (`UIDevice`)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/systemVersion).

Of course it is not possible to compile a different class at runtime as you intend in your Q. There are two ways to handle that:

- Create a class at runtime. Doing so, you need the whole code in methods being compiled and put it together.
- Select the right class (or code fragment as Brandon suggested) from compiled classes at runtime.

There are different approaches of doing that. If it fits good in your structure, you can have one base class with two private subclasses and on instance creation inside the base class you decide, which instance of which subclass to create and to deliver.

Comment: Is this meant for a runtime app or the SDK Used? I'm using the code above but it seems to run the code meant for iOS 9 on an iOS 8 device

Comment: SDK used. What do you mean with "runtime app"? Of course, you cannot decide what to compile depending on what iOS version the app runs, days, years after compiling. Do you want to have the decision on runtime? I can add that.

Comment: Yes that would be better as I can only distribute a single app, there are a couple of issues with webkit under iOS 8 and the wkWebView. It would be best if the decision on which class to use was made at runtime over compile time

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define *at runtime* to which protocols a class conforms as that is a *compiletime* decision. (Actually, there *is* a way using the low-level C API like `class_addProtocol` but that's not needed here. You should not mess with the runtime like that unless you really know what you're doing.)

A protocol is mostly a hint to the compiler about which methods you're going to support. It allows the compiler to issue certain warnings like missing implementations of required protocol methods.

In your case, just define all the protocols that you need (the "union"; in your case: the WKWebView and UIWebView protocols) and implement those methods. Then configure your objects at runtime as needed. That means, somewhere like `viewDidLoad`, decide whether you need a `WKWebView` or `UIWebView` and set it up accordingly. Or, if you're using XIBs, you may want to use two different XIBs (one with WKWebView, another one with UIWebView) and decide at runtime which to load.

Comment: How can `class_addProtocol()` help? Protocols are a typing hint for the compiler. Moreover they enforce the *implementation* of the declared methods. Adding a protocol at runtime, does not do that, so you have a completely meaningless typing.  He has to add methods, not protocols.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: Erm, isn't that what I have written? I've merely mentioned `class_addProtocol` for completeness sake (maybe should have avoided that to avoid confusion): there is a way to add/remove protocols at runtime but you should not and don't need to do that. You can check whether a class conforms to a protocol with `-[AClass conformsToProtocol:@protocol(Foo)]` so in theory, adding a protocol also can make a difference at runtime but I'm not aware of that being used in Cocoa at all. **But my point is:** add _all_ protocols used, implement all the required methods, configure at runtime.

Comment: Of course, adding a protocol can make a difference. That's why this function exists. But adding a protocol cannot make an implementation happen, what is necessary for him.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: I did write that he needs to implement those methods, didn't I? I don't really understand what you're criticising, should my wording have been different/more detailed?

Comment: I simply wanted to say, that even it is a part of your A, it is irrelevant whether a protocol can be added at runtime or not. The task you would have to do is to add implementations for the declared methods. So the first two paragraphs of your answer are at least superflous.